# Concerns about time in between posting

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

Why is there a twenty minute time limit between posting questions?? What if I have two completely unrelated questions and need help on both?

Comment: You'll have to choose wisely between the two of them.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff That seems very unfair.  If I'm totally stuck on two questions and I have nowhere to turn I guess I'll have to post them both at the same time..

Comment: Post one. In the next twenty minutes, think about the other more and, if you're still stuck, write a really good question pertaining to it, full of thoughts and context, and all those things answerers-to-be find so delicious.

Comment: Deleting this question because some two people downvoted..trying to earn my reputation so I can comment.

Comment: @Jeff downvotes in meta don't affect your reputation.

Comment: It's only twenty minutes. Even if it was an hour. so urgent that you ***have to have it right now***? My suggestion is to take those 20 minutes and think more about your question. My experience, as a student as well, is that a well written question often answers itself.

Comment: On marginally related, but since it might be useful information for you: You can only ask [6 questions a day, 50 questions a month](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770) here.

Comment: From [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) you can see that this restriction only for users below 125 reputation points.

Comment: How is it "unfair"? Everyone (under 125 rep) faces that same restriction.

Comment: You could also use those 20 mins to propose some good edits; if they are approved you will get some points for them (+2 for each).

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I guess the 20 minute limit is to prevent spam. Spam in the sense that someone may post a series of spam question to fill the front page with a lot of spam. I guess it is only for low-rep users only, because I remember I had asked two question simultaneously some time in the past. Another reason could be that the SE system wants the user to put some time in formalizing a question so that users could ask a good, well written question; 20 minutes is less IMO, I, for one, usually take one hour minimum and mostly days or a year for a serious question.

Now what you can do is ask the first question and then formalize the other question in the next 20 minutes. If the other question is too small to write or you have already formalized it for some reason then you can think about the comments or answer that you would get on the first answer. If you don't get any response on the first answer, have the other question pre-formalized then I'd suggest you to play Counter-Strike 1.6 multiplayer in those 20 minutes :-p.

Another thing, do not make a new account to circumvent this time limit. Doing this will result in the suspension of your account -- This policy is mentioned by an employee of SE company [here](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1592).

Comment: It might also be there to help prevent spam in the sense of an unsolicited advertisement for goods/services.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Yeah, thats what I am trying to say. I used the word 'spam' because it includes all kind of spams, like, sexually explicit content, advertisements, or whatever.

Comment: You earned my -1 with the last paragraph.

Comment: You last sentence is not precise. You are not allowed to use extra accounts to bypass any restrictions you would face if you only had one account. And the minimum time between posting questions is clearly such a limit.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Could you give me a link to that policy.

Comment: How about you link the part that only mentions those things you have included in your answer?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft link to what? ...the policy. I don't think it is mentioned in the help-centre somewhere. IIRC, to have multiple accounts is, the un-official policy .

Comment: You are making a claim about network-wide policy in the answer, but you cannot back it up with a reference?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes I cannot back it up with a reference. I am claiming it on the behalf of my experience.

Comment: Here is [an official reference](http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/1592): "Trying to do anything with a second account that you could not do with one account is a good way to get your account suspended and deleted unceremoniously. That includes voting multiple times for a post, casting multiple close votes or flags, **exceeding your personal allotment of activities** (daily voting limits, questions, close votes, etc)… and this prohibition goes triple-y so for sock puppet voting (i.e. voting for your own posts). That is a big, huuuge no-no." (my emphasis)

Comment: @quid Thanks, I've changed the answer.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I've edited the answer.